# Is there A Way To Code A Button Or An Icon that Lights Up Or Flashes When A User Is Livestreaming Or Online?

Tags: javascript, css, live-streaming

Hi folks I'm creating a couple apps, the first is a simple one, a Twitch TV app project, in which I'd like to code an icon to show, or a button, to remain lit when a user or users is/are livestreaming or online. I want to integrate maybe rennovate some existing example code that enables the buttons on this page to light up and integrate it into some javascript code See picture below. Is there a common Javascript method that can accomplish this? Or do I  have to "invent the wheel" here?

[image: Stephen KirSchbaums Code Pen for LED buttons]

I want the "Online" button on my page to glow when users or people who I'm following are livestreaming or online. Are there any resources are examples of this concept that you can maybe point me too? Thanks in advance for the help! Much appreciated!

Here is a snapshot of my current roughdraft for my Twitch TV web app:
[image: Twitch TV Web App]

Here is the CSS Code for Stephen Kirschbaums page:

```
.container {
    background-size: cover;
  background: rgb(226,226,226); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(226,226,226,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(219,219,219,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(209,209,209,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(254,254,254,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e2e2e2', endColorstr='#fefefe',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  padding: 20px;
}

.led-box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  float: left;
}

.led-box p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
}

.led-red {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #F00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
  animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-o-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}

.led-yellow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #FF0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #808002 0 -1px 9px, #FF0 0 2px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: blinkYellow 1s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blinkYellow 1s infinite;
  -ms-animation: blinkYellow 1s infinite;
  -o-animation: blinkYellow 1s infinite;
  animation: blinkYellow 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinkYellow {
    from { background-color: #FF0; }
    50% { background-color: #AA0; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #808002 0 -1px 9px, #FF0 0 2px 0; }
    to { background-color: #FF0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinkYellow {
    from { background-color: #FF0; }
    50% { background-color: #AA0; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #808002 0 -1px 9px, #FF0 0 2px 0; }
    to { background-color: #FF0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blinkYellow {
    from { background-color: #FF0; }
    50% { background-color: #AA0; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #808002 0 -1px 9px, #FF0 0 2px 0; }
    to { background-color: #FF0; }
}
@-o-keyframes blinkYellow {
    from { background-color: #FF0; }
    50% { background-color: #AA0; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #808002 0 -1px 9px, #FF0 0 2px 0; }
    to { background-color: #FF0; }
}
@keyframes blinkYellow {
    from { background-color: #FF0; }
    50% { background-color: #AA0; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #808002 0 -1px 9px, #FF0 0 2px 0; }
    to { background-color: #FF0; }
}

.led-green {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #ABFF00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #304701 0 -1px 9px, #89FF00 0 2px 12px;
}

.led-blue {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #24E0FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #006 0 -1px 9px, #3F8CFF 0 2px 14px;
}
```

This is my current CSS Code:

```
container{
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1{
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    /*color: blue;*/
}

.share{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.TV-screen{
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    border-color: 1px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}

.user-status{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;

    display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 100px;
        grid-template-areas:;
            "online-status offline-status online-and-offline";
}

.online-status{
font-size: 1.5em;
}

.offline-status{
font-size: 1.5em;
}

.online-and-offline{
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Twitch TV.css">
<title>

</title>

</head> 
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Twitch TV Web App</h1>

    <div class="share">
    share: linkedin facebook twitter
    </div>

    <div class="TV-screen">

    </div>

    <div class="user-status">
    <button id ="on" type="button" class="online-status" >Online</button>
    <button id ="off" type="button" class="offline-status" >Offline</button>
    <button id ="all" type="button" class="online-and-offline" >All</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is "Is there A Way To Code A Button Or An Icon that Lights Up Or Flashes When A User Is Livestreaming Or Online?" The answer is yes. But i think you are looking for more than that. Why not editting this answer an maybe make it about your program with the light and not about the light working on someone's else PEN

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO, I just did an edit. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: A little better. But still we need to focus on your app. I can't help you in integrating this LED/CSS animation, if i don't have any code to work on.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO, I just did another edit...hopefully this edit is better...

Comment: Ok we got your CSS, what is your question. What have you tried, what are you trying to achive. Don't we need some HTML so we can add the two ``<div>`` 's and one ``<p> tag that the light needs?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO, my question is how do I get my Online button to automatically glow/light up when Twitch TV users that I'm following are livestreaming/or online? My aim is to achieve this process via some javascript code....

Comment: You should look for a twitch API.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO, I have the Twitch API info already...I just want to enable my Online button to glow when my followers are online....

Comment: Do yuo know what event or response you get for this accion?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO, no I don't. but I've seen stuff along the lines of `if(result.loggedin == "1"){.....etc...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165250/discussion-between-gerardo-blanco-and-codebwoy).

Answer (score -3):

There is specific javascript events for that...
For online purpose use `online()` event...[Here's a simple example...](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ononline.asp)

And for livestreaming use `onplay` event....[Here's a simple example...](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_play.asp)

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, 
[you will be able to post comments](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: The question is about a Twitch stream going online (starting a live stream), not the user's browser.

Comment: @NiklasHigi, I want to find out how can I get my Online button to automatically glow/light up when Twitch TV users that I'm following are livestreaming/or online? My aim is to achieve this process via some javascript code....